# Should I wait to merge Git grandchild branch to master until child branch is merged to master?

Tags: git, merge, branch

In my team project, I was working on a `feature` branch that was branched off from `master.` I've raised a pull request for `feature`, and it's undergoing review but it's going be a while before I can merge it.

Meanwhile, I'm working on something that relies on the code I implemented in `feature` but is not related enough to be actually implemented in the same branch. So I branched off of `feature`, like this:

```
master
└── feature
    └── different_feature
```

If I raise a pull request for `different_feature` and it gets approved before `feature`, can I simply merge it to `master`? Or am I supposed to wait to merge `different_feature` until `feature` gets merged to `master`?

My concern about the first option is, later when you check the log, some parts of `feature` are going to be merged to `master` in `fghij`, when in truth it should be merged in `abcde`. This could be inconvenient if we wanted to keep `different_feature` but get rid of `feature` (rollback).

```
git log (from newest to oldest - with dummy commit hashes)

abcde Merge pull request: feature
fghij Merge pull request: different_feature
klmno Merge pull request: something_implemented_before_all_this
```

Thanks in advance.

**[EDIT]** Forgot to mention this: I've made some additional commits to `feature` after I branched `different_feature` from it. So `different_feature` only partially inherits the updates made in `feature.`

**[Update]** Ultimately, I waited till `feature` was merged to `master`, and then rebased `different_feature` onto `master` before merging it to `master` as well. This allowed me to separate the updates done in `feature` vs those done in `different_feature`.

As a side note, when raising the pull request for `different_feature`, I learned that you can compare only the changes that you made in this branch by setting the base branch of your request to `feature` instead of `master`. Just make sure to change it back to `master` when you merge that pull request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the situation you describe (I added a few example commits to reason on)

```
A---B---C <<< master
         \
          D---E <<< feature
               \
                F---G <<< different_feature
```

A pull request for `feature > master` would bring only commits `D` and `E`, but another pull request for `different_feature > master` would bring `D`, `E`, `F` and `G`.

If you try a pull request `feature > master` AFTER `different_feature > master` has already been accepted/merged, there will be nothing left to merge and it will result in a no-op.

Also, to be noted, nothing will prevent you from reverting `feature` commits (`D` and `E`) at a later point without reverting F and G, **provided you don't squash commits during the merge**.

---

**Edit after comments**

The actual situation seems to be more like

```
A---B---C <<< master
         \
          D---E---H---I <<< feature
               \
                F---G <<< different_feature
```

But the overall principle is the same, if you remember that git fundamentally works on the base of commits, not branches.

Situation after the first PR (`J` is the merge commit)

```
A---B---C---------------J <<< master
         \             /
          D---E---F---G <<< different_feature
               \
                H---I <<< feature
```

The `different_feature > master` pull request will bring `D`, `E`, `F`, and `G` commits into `master`, and if merged first, it will only let `H` and `I` left to be merged in the second pull request, which will be recalculated after the first one is merged.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Actually, I don't think that's the case because I've been adding new commits to `feature` after I branched off `different_feature` from it (I made some amendments based on the feedback I got in the pull request for `feature`). In other words, `different_feature` inherits a part of `feature` but not all of it.

Comment: So to use your diagram as an example, there are some newer commits after `D` and `E` in `feature`.

Comment: OK, I get it but then the situation is a bit different. I'll edit.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I should've mentioned the additional commits in my initial question.

Comment: __[Post-edit]__ Thank you. You've made a perfect diagram of the situation. So, going back to my original question - is it inadvisable to merge `G` to master before `I`, if `D` and `E` are part of `feature` and not of `different_feature` ?

Comment: @Risa No solid answer on the point, since it will eventually depend on the nature of the changes. It could be more straightforward in complex cases to merge things following chronological order of introduced changes, and merge `feature` before `different_feature`, but in simpler contexts it also may be an unnecessary constraint.

Comment: Hmm ok. I guess I should ask my team about this specific case then. I asked here because I wanted to know if there was any agreed best practice for this kind of scenario. Thank you!